# Accessing all the cells when a button in a cell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell. Each cell has a button in it and I would like to make all the buttons unclickable when one button is clicked. It is easy to access the cell that contains the clicked button but I need also to access all the other cells to make their button unclickable.

So when a button is clicked inside a cell, I need to loop through all the other cells... I found a way to walk up the hierarchy so that in the button action method, I go up one layer above to access the UITableView and from there I can access each cell and from each cell I can access their button and edit the isUserInteractionEnabled property. However this doesn't seem to be a good practice to make a cell access the TableView and then all the other cells.

```swift
class AnswerCell2: UITableViewCell {

let answerTextButton: UIButton = {
        let answerButton = UIButton()
        answerButton.setTitle("initial text", for: .normal)
        return answerButton
    }()


override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

       answerTextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func answerClicked(sender: UIButton) {
// HERE I CAN ACCESS EASILY THE CELL WHERE THE BUTTON WAS CLICKED 
// AND THEN USE THE TABLEVIEW TO ACCESS OTHER CELLS AND THEIR BUTTONS 
// BUT THIS IS NOT A NICE WAY
    }
```

So I have a solution as I said but I'd like more a nice way to do it. All the solutions I find online are about how to access the cell where the button was clicked but this one is easy, what I need is to access the other cells and I would like to avoid doing so in the answerClicked() action method if possible so that the code stays clean.

Thanks.

Comment: If a button is clicked once and all others are made unclickable, then when can other button become clickable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `closure` in custom `UITableViewCell` and call it whenever a `button` is pressed in the `cell`, i.e.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var handler: (()->())?

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        handler?()
    }
}
```

Now, set the `closure` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method and use `visibleCells` property to *enable/disable* the `buttons` in other `cells`, i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.handler = {
        if let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as? [TableViewCell] {
            visibleCells.forEach({
                $0.button.isEnabled = ($0 === cell)
            })
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

In case you want to persist the *enable/disable* `button` states while reloading, you need to store in your `model`.

Comment: You would need to persist the setting somewhere if there is a chance that the table could still be scrolled and display new cells not updated through `visibleCells`.  In this case the current state (could just be a bool on the VC)  would be needed in `cellForRowAt` to ensure those cells also had their buttons correctly enabled/disabled.

Comment: Thanks @PGDev, it seems to be a good solution, I'll go for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to walk the hierarchy and specifically change the characteristics of the existing cells on screen.

Just store a value which represents the index of the selected button.

```
var indexPathForSelectedButton: IndexPath?
```

Anytime this changes, update the index in `func answerClicked(sender: UIButton)` and reload the table view.

in the cell for at method, check if the current indexPath is the same as the stored one and if so enable the button, disable if not

Comment: Reloading the entire table view is a bit drastic. It would be better to reload the visible cells or even update the button in the visible cells directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Not really, only the visible cells would be reloaded anyway due to reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Scriptable, I selected the other answer because I wanted to avoid accessing the tableview from the cell (my answerClicked is in the custom cell class), unless I misunderstood your response.

Comment: @Scriptable it might be i in this case but if you have variable height cells you can get flickering and cells jumping as the tableview needs to recalculate the offscreen heights.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in a relatively light-weight approach thorugh either closures or delegate functions.  Given tableView is already delegate-heavy I'd slightly prefer that approach.

create a simple protocol to allow the cell to inform the viewController

```
protocol CellStateRespondable {  //I'm sure there are better protocol names than this!
  var buttonsAreEnabled: Bool
  func cellButtonChangedSate(enabled: Bool)
}
```

Add a delegate variable to your AnswerCell2 class

```
weak var delegate: CellStateRespondable?
```

and adapt your`answerClicked(sender: UIButton)` to call the delegate method

```
delegate?.cellButtonChangedState(enabled: sender.isEnabled)
```

make the ViewController (or other controller if you separate out tableView delegate functions) comply with the protocol through adding the variable and function, and add the function implementation

var buttonsAreEnabled = true

```
func cellButtonChangedSate(enabled: Bool) {
  buttonsAreEnabled = enabled
  if let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as? [AnswerCell2] {
    visibleCells.forEach {
      $0.button.isEnabled = enabled
    }
  }
}
```

and then adapt your `cellForRowAt` to set the delegate and the state of the button when creating the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = //dequeue cell and configure as normal
  cell.delegate. = self
  cell.button.isEnabled = buttonsAreEnabled
  return cell
}
```